# AI does not stop walking like it is supposed to, instead spins in place and lags game

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, ai

I've got this very simple enemy AI that follows the player and is supposed to stop and shoot at the player when he enters a trigger, however it doesn't seem to do that it doesn't stop or shoot. This is one of my first scripts so it isn't really good. Any and all help will be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour

{
    public GameObject Destination;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Collider TriggerCollider;
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public float EjectionForce;
    public float firingrate = 20f;
    private float NextFire = 0f;
    public GameObject GunArea;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.SetDestination(Destination.transform.position);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


    }
    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Player" && Time.time >= NextFire)
        {
            agent.isStopped = true;
            AimAndShoot();
            NextFire = Time.time + 1f / firingrate;
        }
        else agent.isStopped = false;
        agent.SetDestination(Destination.transform.position);
    }
    void AimAndShoot()
    {
        Enemy.transform.LookAt(Destination.transform.position);
        GameObject enemybullet = Instantiate(bullet, GunArea.transform.position, GunArea.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        enemybullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(enemybullet.transform.forward * EjectionForce);
        Destroy(enemybullet, 1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've misspelled OnTriggerEnter — please make sure you're using the correct method names from the documentation.

Comment: I fixed the ontrigger issue, so it will shoot with ontriggerstay, however, the ai does not stop when i enter the trigger zone, it also randomly spins around on areas that have a regular navmesh

Comment: Please edit your question to describe that issue in detail. Note that "Doesn't work like intended" as a title doesn't advertise what you need very well: if things were working as intended, you wouldn't be posting here at all. That means we already know that much before we even read your title. So, use that space to describe the issue itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you sure `OnTriggerStay` is called at all? A simple

```
print("OnTriggerStay was called!");
```

at the beginning of `OnTriggerStay` would tell you. If it's **not** called, make sure the "Is Trigger" property in the collider component of your enemy is ticked (set to true). You should find this in the inspector after clicking the enemy game object.

Second, Unity [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html) says:

> Trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a rigidbody attached.

Do the enemy or the player (or both) has a rigidbody component?

Third, you set `agent.isStopped` both to true and false in the same function (`OnTriggerStay`), which is called over and over again (once per physics update), so maybe `agent.isStopped` is set to true, then false, then true again and so on and so forth, and it happens so fast you don't notice the enemy stopping. I assume you want to set `agent.isStopped` to false in `OnTriggerExit` instead.

Comment: @Merpysoup2, what solved the problem? Also, can you please vote up the answer if it helped you? Thanks :)